# AWS Elastic Bean Codigniter 404 issue with all controller except default one

Tags: php

PHP Version 7.4, Codeigniter Version 3.1.11

**My Controllers**

- Home.php

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Home extends CI_Controller {

public function allcourse()
    {
-------
-------
}

}
```

=====================================

- Aboutus.php
- Contactus.php

**My Routes**

```
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['all-course'] = "home/allcourse";
$route['about-us'] = "aboutus";
$route['contact-us'] = "contactus";
```

**My application nginx custom file is**

```
.platform
  -nginx
     -conf.d
        -custom.conf
-Application
-Controller
-Views
-Model
...
...
..

files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      server {
        server_name http://XXXX.elb.amazonaws.com/;

        root /var/www;
        index index.html index.php;

        location / {
                # Check if a file or directory index file exists, else route it to index.php.
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }
    }
```

**Error Description**

- Home default controller working fine
- if we add index.php before countroller name then it works fine
- but without index.php it is showing me below error

```
404 Not Found
nginx/1.18.0
```

Please help!!!

Comment: `.htaccess` is for Apache servers but it appears you're using NGINX.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Elastic Beanstalk + Laravel, Nginx Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61734222/aws-elastic-beanstalk-laravel-nginx-configuration)

Comment: Thanks Phil, I added nginx configuration but still my index.php is need to add in url without it is showing 404 Not found error